# Video Player Not Loading the File

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am trying this to load the video from the Project directory , can any one suggest , what exactly i am missing .

```
NSURL *myURL =[[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:@"US_Very_High_Dive_Boudia_US_44_x264"   
withExtension:@"mp4"];

MPMoviePlayerController *player =
[[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL: myURL];

[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self    
selector:@selector(moviePlayBackDidFinish:)    
name:MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification object:player];


[player prepareToPlay];
[player shouldAutoplay];
[player allowsAirPlay];
[self.view addSubview:player.view];
[player setFullscreen:YES animated:YES];

player.controlStyle=MPMovieControlStyleEmbedded;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this code

In .h file add the following

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) MPMoviePlayerController *controller;
```

In .m file

```
 -(IBAction)playMovie:(id)sender

           {
                NSString *filepath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"buyTutorial" ofType:@"mov"];
                NSURL *fileURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:filepath];
                MPMoviePlayerController *moviePlayerController = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL:fileURL];
                [self.view addSubview:moviePlayerController.view];
                moviePlayerController.fullscreen = YES;
            [moviePlayerController prepareToPlay];
                [moviePlayerController play];
        [self setController:moviePlayerController];
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems like You are not setting URL properly - try this:

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle]
pathForResource:@"filename" ofType:@"mp4"]];
```